# Parsing in Json not in XML . VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, json.net

At the moment I am using VB.Net.
I build my string, post it out and then parse the results.

Parsing Example for XML

```
Dim xml As New MWXMLDocument()
            Dim sReason As String = "Unknown"

            Try
                xml.LoadXml(sresult)
                If xml.SelectSimpleNode("AcceptedLead").InnerText = "true" Then
                    app.Outcome.RedirectURL = xml.SelectSimpleNode("result/redirecturl").InnerText

                    AcceptLead()
                    Return True
                End If

                sReason = xml.SelectSimpleNode("Reason").InnerText
            Catch ex As Exception
                sReason = "Error: " & ex.Message
            End Try
            DeclineLead(sReason)
            Return False
        End Function
```

How would I parse a result sent back in JSON, here is an example of the result I want to parse in using VB : Can i not just get the data from the string and parse as normal XML.

```
{"RedirectUrl":"www.test.com","Commission":5.0000,"Status":"accepted"}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse json in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Comment: Also look into [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete Answer

```
sResult = sResult.Replace("""", String.Empty)
            If sResult.Contains("Status:accepted") Then
                Dim parts = sResult.Replace("{", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty).Split(",")
                For i As Int16 = 0 To parts.Length - 1
                    If parts(i).StartsWith("RedirectUrl") Then
                        app.Outcome.RedirectURL = parts(i).Substring(12)
                    End If
                    If parts(i).StartsWith("Commission") Then
                        lendertier.LenderComm = CDec(parts(i).Substring(11))
                    End If
                    If parts(i).StartsWith("ApplicationRef") Then
                        app.Outcome.LenderReference = parts(i).Substring(15)
                    End If
                Next
                AcceptLead()
                Return True
            End If
            If sResult.Contains("Reason:Duplicate") Then
                sReason = "Duplicate"
            ElseIf sResult.Contains("{Error:invalid credentials") Then
                sReason = "Error: Invalid credentials"
            ElseIf sResult.Contains("ValidationErrors:") Then
                sReason = "Invalid call:" + sResult.Replace("ValidationErrors:", String.Empty).Replace(",Status:rejected", String.Empty)
            Else
                sReason = "Rejected"
            End If
            DeclineLead(sReason)
            Return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JSON.NET Library](http://james.newtonking.com/)

Example in C#:

`var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string json);`

The `RootObject` should be your own class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the .Net built in JavaScriptSerialiser

First add a reference to System.Web.Extensions and then

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

Followed by...

```
Dim sExampleJSON As String = "{""RedirectUrl"":""www.test.com"",""Commission"":5.0000,""Status"":""accepted""}"

Dim MySerializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim MyDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = MySerializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(sExampleJSON)

If MyDictionary.ContainsKey("RedirectUrl") Then
  Console.WriteLine(MyDictionary("RedirectUrl"))
End If
```

Comment: What if the sExampleJSON string value changes, i just added that as an example.

Comment: Well then you just deserialise it again. The MyDictionary will then contain the new deserialised JSON results.

Comment: could you provide an example please

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, an example of what exactly?

Comment: I understand all of your example, but i dont understand Dim **** sExampleJSON As String = "{""RedirectUrl"":""www.test.com"",""Commission"":5.0000,""Status"":""accepted""}"  ***** , those value's you filled in , how do i collect those value's after the result has been sent back to me

Comment: That's just an example. From your code above I suspect this is in your xml.SelectSimpleNode("result/redirecturl").InnerText, but I can't say for sure. Don't you know where your JSON is? because you don't make that clear in your code above. You've asked how to parse JSON and both these answers tell you how. If you've a wider coding question (and it certainly looks like you do) then you must expand your question to ask it. There's not a lot more I can add without getting into an extended discussion. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

in global.asax.cs

```
using System.Data.Entity;

   namespace RpManticSolAPI
  {
  public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
          GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
          GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
          GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);          
      }
  }
  }
```